# Sql parse error, save result in sql variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, sql

I try to delete a row of my Table by receiving `$delwebsite, $delusername, $delpassword` from a submit form. Then I have a (working) sql expression `$sqlselect` where I get the id of the row.

The Problem:

> "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$id' (T_VARIABLE)" when I try
>   to execute $sqlselect and save the result in $id.

I think its a very easy problem but I can't find it.

```html
<?php
 IF(ISSET($_POST['delete']))
 {
    $delwebsite = $_POST['delWebsite'];
    $delusername = $_POST['delUsername'];
    $delpassword = $_POST['delPassword'];
    $sqlselect = "SELECT id FROM $loc_username WHERE website = $delwebsite AND username = $delusername AND password = $delpassword";
    $id = mysql_query($sqlselect);
    $sqldelete = "DELETE FROM $loc_username WHERE id = $id";
    if(mysql_query($sqldelete)){
    .......
    }
 }
```

Comment: `$sqldelete = "DELETE FROM $loc_username WHERE id = $id"`;
in this statement you are using a variable $id, its not defined anywhere. thats why the error

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated and removed in PHP7. Use mysqli_* functions instead or PDO.

Comment: cant I define it like this:  $id = mysql_query($sqlselect);

Comment: Your queries are vulnerable to SQL injections. Please read : [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: i don't understand why you are fetching data from db and then try to delete? if you want to delete something, use one query  `DELETE FROM $loc_username WHERE website = $delwebsite AND username = $delusername AND password = $delpassword";` this would do the trick

Comment: The statement ```$id = mysql_query($sqlselect)``` does not put the ID returned by the query into the variable $id. $id will be an result object. You would need to use that object to fetch a row from the result, which would then contain the column values.

Comment: Very important! Do not use the mysql_ functions. They are depreciated, and are not even in the current version of PHP. Also, as mentioned by @Syscall, your query is vunerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Not reproductible : https://eval.in/981661 : no syntax error.

Comment: "Your queries are vulnerable to SQL injections. " To rephrase that: if I am on youw website, I can delete your entire database within 10 seconds. That might alarm you a little bit more if you are not familiar with SQL injection. You should. Also you should never store passwords in a database. All in all: you are VERY wise to take a crash course on security in PHP/MySQL. Really, but for real. Do it.

Comment: thanks guys, are the msqli functions more secure??